# Django circular imports causes AttributeError: module 'x' has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, django, import

I'm trying to import two Serializers like below:

```py
# project/accounts/serializers/user.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = ...  # I need TeamSerializer here

# -----------------------------------

# project/teams/serializers/team.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leader = ...  # I need UserSerializer here
```

All of the serializers in every apps are in a `serializers` folder and the folder contains an init file. Inside the init files, I've imported Serializer like below:

```py
# project/teams/serializers/__init__.py
from .team import TeamSerializer

# project/accounts/serializers/__init__.py
from .user import UserSerializer
```

I've already tried many ways like `import teams.serializers` and call `teams.serializers.TeamSerializers()` instead `from teams.serializers import TeamSerializer`.
It only works when it's not circular, however, I need them both in each other. When I import them in both files, there is an error like below:

```py
AttributeError: module 'accounts' has no attribute 'serializers'
```

Once I comment out one of them, the error is gone.

Is there a clean way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to work? Looks like an endless loop to me if a `UserSerializer` has a field serialised by a `TeamSerializer` which in turn has a field serialised by a `UserSerializer`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Well, each team has a user and each user has a team. I need these serializers in each other to show the details of the objects. What's the solution?

Comment: And where does this nested recursion stop? That's an endless recursion.

Comment: @dirkgroten That's exactly my question. What do I do? Java Spring has an annotation to stop this in depth 1. I can do that manually but I want a clean way to do that in Django.

Comment: You can set `depth = 1` in the serializer's `Meta` class (not sure if it works if you nest serializers recursively like this). But as to the import issue, that cannot be resolved, you need to have both serializers in the same file. At least try it to see if the nesting works. Otherwise you'll have to decide: One of the two serializers should just use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I appreciate your help.